# We have a problem, where given: $P(F)=0.2$, P(R)=0.1, and $P(F\cap R)=0.04$. Why $P(F\cap R)= 0.04$ and not $P(F)\cdot P(R)=0.02$?

Tags: probability

I have a math problem in a course, where the following probabilities are given: $P(F)=0.2$, $P(R)=0.1$, and $P(F\cap R)=0.04$, but I can't understand why $P(F\cap R)= 0.04$ and not $P(F)\times P(R)=0.02$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The data is not statistically independent

Comment: what do you mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If two events are statistically independent then the chance of one occuring is the same whether the other event occurred or not. Only when two events are statistically independent can you say that their intersection is the same as the product of each event individually. Otherwise, the intersection can take any value.

Comment: ok got it !!! thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If we have independence for two events, then we could use mentioned product rule for probability of $P(f \cap R)=p(f).p(R)$.

Comment: got it, thanks!